# naming and getting a particular connection in typeorm

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, nest

Previously, typeorm seems to have allowed the use of a `ConnectionManager` that seems to have allowed to name a particular connection whilst creation and fetch/check the connection with the same name [like this](https://thomasvds.com/schema-based-multitenancy-with-nest-js-type-orm-and-postgres-sql/):

```
import { Connection, createConnection, getConnectionManager } from 'typeorm';
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';

import * as tenantsOrmconfig from '../../tenants-orm.config';

export function getTenantConnection(tenantId: string): Promise<Connection> {
  const connectionName = `tenant_${tenantId}`;
  const connectionManager = getConnectionManager();

  if (connectionManager.has(connectionName)) {
    const connection = connectionManager.get(connectionName);
    return Promise.resolve(connection.isConnected ? connection : connection.connect());
  }

  return createConnection({
    ...(tenantsOrmconfig as PostgresConnectionOptions),
    name: connectionName,
    schema: connectionName,
  });
}
```

But, I'm confused now as to how to achieve this when I'm using a `Datasource` using a factory to create dynamic connection:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const host = configService.get('MY_DB_HOST');
        const port = parseInt(configService.get('MY_DB_PORT'));
        const user = configService.get('MY_DB_USER');
        const password = configService.get('MY_DB_PASSWORD');
        const dbName = configService.get('MY_DB_NAME');
        
        return {
          type: 'postgres',
          host: host,
          port: port,
          username: user,
          password: password,
          database: dbName,
          entities: entities,
          synchronize: true,
        };
      }
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

I'm trying to fetch an existing connection from the connection pool which typeorm is supposed to manage by default if it already exists, and that connection is supposed to belong to a tenant if it exists, else it should create a new connection for the tenant.  **How do I do this with a `Datasource`?**

I can see that there is a `datasourceInstance.manager.find()` method, but, that seems to take an `Entity` which seems to query the database, and I can't find anything more useful in the docs.

Comment: did you find more information?

Comment: I had same issue, I'm finding the answer but not